# Replacing if statement C++

Tags: c++, if-statement

I want to realize this simple C++ program:

```
(if y>0) x=2; else x=10;
```

but without the use of an `if` statement or any other statement such as `for`, `while`, `do while`, `switch` or `?`.

Is it possible? I am still wondering about this.

Comment: How would you perform the comparison without any of the constructs you mentioned?

Comment: I think it would be beneficial both for those who provide answers and those who will encounter your question and for learning purpose that you say why you have such a constraint -- i.e., not using any of the conditional statements. One possible explanation that comes up to my mind is that for some reason you are simulating a scenario in which a compiler or a CPU that don't have a JUMP instruction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this: `x = 2 + (y <= 0) * 8;` A boolean expression converted to an integral value is either `0` or `1`, which you can use to add optional summands.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option:

```
x = 10;
y > 0 && (x=2);
```

Not really recommended, but it works.